# Obtener el valor más alto y sumarle uno cada vez

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:

| Codigo | Descripcion | Grupo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uno | 1 |
| 2 | Dos | 1 |
| 3 | Tres | 2 |
| 4 | Cuatro | 2 |
| 5 | Cinco | NULL |
| 6 | Seis | NULL |

Lo que necesito es conseguir una consulta que sin modificar la tabla, a los grupos que están en NULL, les añada un valor que en el primero será el último + 1, y el resto uno más que el anterior, quedando el resultado de la consulta así

| Codigo | Descripcion | Grupo_Ok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uno | 1 |
| 2 | Dos | 1 |
| 3 | Tres | 2 |
| 4 | Cuatro | 2 |
| 5 | Cinco | **3** |
| 6 | Seis | **4** |

He llegado con esta SELECT a hacer algo casi, pero no me pone el 4, me pone los dos NULL's con un 3

```
SELECT Codigo, Descripcion 
       Grupo_Ok = CASE WHEN Grupo IS NULL 
                      THEN (SELECT MAX(Grupo) FROM tabla)  + 1 ELSE Grupo END 
FROM tabla 
ORDER BY Grupo_Ok
```

Ya estoy bloqueado y no me quedan ideas.

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar los siguientes pasos lógicos para obtener el resultado:

1. Determinar el valor de grupo más alto almacenado actualmente en la tabla
2. Obtener todas las filas que no tienen grupo y al valor obtenido en el paso anterior sumarle el número de fila, obtenido con la función `row_number()`.
3. Unir los resultados de las filas de la tabla que si tienen grupo con los de la consulta anterior.

Una consulta que implementa los pasos descritos sería como esta a continuación:

```
select Codigo, Descripcion, Grupo
  from Tabla
 where Grupo is not null
union all
select Codigo, Descripcion, coalesce((select MAX(Grupo) from Tabla), 0) + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Codigo) 
  from Tabla
 where Grupo is null
 order by Grupo, Codigo;
```

Te daría el siguiente resultado:

```
Codigo      Descripcion Grupo
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           Uno         1
2           Dos         1
3           Tres        2
4           Cuatro      2
5           Cinco       3
6           Seis        4

(6 rows affected)

Completion time: 2023-05-19T12:41:35.4086586-06:00
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!!!, no se me había ocurrido tomar ese camino.